# Confuse with MOVZX

Tags: assembly, delphi

I'm trying to reverse engineer an app. I can't understand some instructions:

```
EBP-4h=>Self
EBP-8h=>OptionData
...
mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
movzx   eax, byte ptr [eax+1Ch]      // (1)
mov     edx, [ebp+var_8]
mov     [edx+8], eax
mov     eax, [ebp+var_4]
movzx   eax, byte ptr [eax+1Dh]     // (2)
mov     edx, [ebp+var_8]
mov     [edx+0Ch], eax
mov     eax, [ebp+var_8]
mov     dword ptr [eax+10h], 1F41h  // (3)
...
```

Based on reversing other parts of the app, I believe edx+8, edx+0C, edx+10 are all integers; eax+1C is 'scP8B' and eax+1D is 'ocDynamicMR2'.

I don't understand instructions (1) and (2).

Comment: did you try to look up this instruction in any documentation?

Comment: If you are using IDA, you can turn on Auto comments, this option will explain some "basic information" for you. The answer for this question is @Henno Brandsma's response!

Answer (score 3):

`eax + 0x1c` is a pointer to bytes, and the value of the byte at that address is put into the register `eax` where the byte value is “zero-extended” (hence the mov*zx*), so that e.g. a byte `0xdf` would become a dword `0x000000df`, so not sign-extended. So in C: `eax = (unsigned int) b[0x1c]`, where `unsigned char *b` is the pointer stored in `var_4`, say.

Comment: A nice link to some place where the questioner could [look up opcodes](http://ref.x86asm.net/) in the future would have been awesome. After all none of this is magic and the question is at the level of "please do my homework".